# URL rewrite conditions in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I need some help with `.htaccess`. I've been using URL rewrites, but not conditions, and I'm pretty sure I need them seeing as I can't get this working.

The URL structure I need is -> `forum/catnamehere` (which shows the page called catnamehere)
and child structure -> `forum/catnamehere/fornamehere` (which shows the child page of the cat)

However, somehow I fail to do this, making me believe I need conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with two rules.

Put your .htaccess file in the forum directory, and add the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(/?)$ complexForumPath.php?catName=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(/?)$ complexForumPath.php?catName=$1&subPage=$2 [QSA]
```

The first rule will grab stuff like forum/abc123_

And the second rule will grab forum/abc123_/abc123_